# ionic 4 - which is the Best way for ngx-translate?

Tags: angular, ionic4, ngx-translate

**Hi**

for **multi-language** app with **ionic 4** i use [ngx-translate](http://www.ngx-translate.com/) , but it is **3 way** for using that, i want know which is better and why *? if you know other way please guide*

1 - using storage and for every page getting language value and depends it translate (*ngx-translate*) take language

2 - using event by create event in setting (choose language) and create a listener to the event in `app.component.ts` that set language by ngx-translate

3 - like number 2 create an event but create listener in every page

Thanks

Comment: I have one question that, I have the select box for changing the language in the custom component in Ionic and I am setting the default language in the custom component but It is not showing the language in the app. Do I have to set language in the app.component.ts only.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: you should add to every page that you want be multi language